# LOD calculation how to wirte in DAX Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

{ FIXED  [ID] : MIN(

IF [Temp] >= 0  AND [Temp] <= 35.2  THEN  [Value]
END

)}

How to write the same calculation in DAX

Comment: which language is this ?

Comment: This Tableau LOD Calculation

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
FIXED[ID] =
MINX ( FILTER ( YourTable, [Temp] >= 0 && [Temp] <= 35.2 ), [Value] )
```

Comment: You're welcome, Jana. Stay safe.

Comment: IF [Temp]= { Fixed [Customer ID]: MAX([Temp])} THEN  Value
END
Can you help me on this ?

Comment: Hi, Jana. You need to explain your "if" logic on this formula. I don't understand anything from this: DAX <> Tableau 

Comment: Actually I have written the same calculation in Tableau Using LOD. I would like to write the same in DAX to use in Power BI.